# SBT: cannot resolve dependency that used to work before

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, sbt-assembly

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
import sbt._

name := "spark-jobs"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.2.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

This used to work until I decided to see what happens if I add another `% "provided"` at the end of `spark-streaming_2.11`. It failed to resolve dependency, I moved on and reverted the change. But, it seems to give me the exception after that as well. Now my build.sbt looks exactly like it used to when everything worked. Still, it gives me this exception :

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming_2.11;2.2.0: org.apache.spark#spark-parent_2.11;2.2.0!spark-parent_2.11.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/aswin/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-parent_2.11/2.2.0/spark-parent_2.11-2.2.0.pom
```

SBT's behavior is a bit confusing to me. Could someone guide me to as why this could happen? Any good blogs/ resources to understand how exactly SBT works under the hood is also welcome.

Here is my project/assembly.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version = 1.0.4
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("artifactory", url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in sbt console, just run `reload` command and try again. After you update your dependencies or sbt plugins, you need to reload the project so that the changes take effect.

By the way, instead of defining the Scala version in your dependencies, you can just use `%%` operator and it will fetch the appropriate dependency according to your defined scala version.

```
// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0"
)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be the issue. Tried it. Still getting the same exception..

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me with an empty project (just your example with these corrections). Have you tried cleaning up your Ivy cache and see if it helps? (usually located at `$HOME/.ivy2/cache`)